# WPF static property binding not working on a list view

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I'm currently binding a list view to a list of objects and everytrhing is working.

I can bind fine to my code behind of the xaml as long as I put in my Window element `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

My ListView looks like this and bindings work correctly for my binded columns to the properties of the items of MyCollection.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
```

For one of the columns though I always want it to say the same thing.  For example this column would always contain "Hello World"

The following code gives me an error for binding:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="I want all fields to be Hello World" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=MyNamespace.MyStaticClass},Path=MyStaticStringField}" />
```

I get the error:

> error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'MyNamespace'. Note that type names are case sensitive.

**MyNamespace is the same namespace as the window itself and MyStaticClass is public**

If I try instead:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="I want all fields to be Hello World" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=MyStaticClass},Path=MyStaticStringField}" />
```

I get the error:

> error MC3029: 'MyStaticClass' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

**Strangely enough, when I do this it works:**

```
<GridViewColumn Header="This works" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=SystemFonts.IconFontFamily}, Path=Source}" />
```

**The code for the field I'm trying to bind to:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static string MyStaticStringField{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the related code for the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `x:Static` you need to specify a path to a static field or property (not just class).

```
<GridViewColumn Header="I want all fields to be Hello World" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static MyNamespace:MyStaticClass.MyStaticStringField}}" />
```

Also note that the namespace is separated from class name with colon (not dot).

Comment: This gives me a parse exception thrown at runtime.

Comment: @wpf, Have you read what Pavlo written or only copy-pasted directly into your code? Also looking in the error details may help a lot. Otherwise it only wastes our time.

Comment: @wpf pro pls - Yeap, noticed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you!  It is so strange to me that `<GridViewColumn Header="This works" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=SystemFonts.IconFontFamily}, Path=Source}" />` works but not what I was trying with the namespace before it.  Do you know why?

Comment: BTW also if anyone else finds this thread you need to put the namespace as defined in your window ns not the actual namespace before the member.

Comment: @wpf pro pls - That's because in case of `{x:Static Member=SystemFonts.IconFontFamily}` the static member is specified, but in your case you were trying to specify a class - not member! `{x:Static Member=MyNamespace.MyStaticClass}`

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to include the namespace

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

and then use it like this:

```
{x:Static Member=local:MyStaticClass}
```

Comment: I have already put in my window element: xmlns:rm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly" and then prefixed just the class name on the Source with rm:, but it gives me the same error as the second error: error MC3029: 'MyStaticClass' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

Answer (score 2):

You can not bind directly to a class including the Namespace

set the NameSpace in the Page or Window or Usercontrol Declaration with
xmlns:mynamespace="pathtoyournamespace"

and reference it in the binding like that: {x:Static mynamespace:MyStaticClass}, Path....

Comment: you have to declare the namespace in XAML.

Comment: I have already put in my window element: 
`xmlns:rm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"` and then prefixed just the class name on the `Source` with `rm:`, but it gives me the same error as the second error: error MC3029: 'MyStaticClass' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

Answer (score 0):

Also adding to other answers `x:static` should be bound to static class **MEMBER**, not the class itself.

Comment: Pls suggest the proper syntax

Comment: Pavlo written correct syntax, but you should have `MyStaticStringField` static field in your static class